# What does spade (♠) mean in scientific notation?

Tags: notation

Example: $\spadesuit 3.5×10^2$

The Wikipedia page about [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) ([permalink](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Scientific_notation&oldid=799301362)) didn't help. Neither did the ["Val" template page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Val) ([permalink](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:Val&oldid=674925404)).

---

Here's a screenshot of what shows up for me:

[image]

Comment: Where did you see this symbol used? What was the context?

Comment: Are you missing a font or something?

Comment: @Argon It's linked in the question. I'll post the links again: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Val

Comment: I don't see that symbol on those pages.

Comment: @Batman Maybe. If that's the case, I'll close the question. Any idea how to fix it? Do you not see the spade symbol?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably missing a font that displays "Miscellaneous Technical" symbols in Unicode.  The Wikipedia page has this boxed note in the right hand margin:

> This article contains Unicode "Miscellaneous Technical" characters. Without proper rendering support, you may see question marks, boxes, or other symbols instead of "₁₀" (Decimal Exponent Symbol U+23E8 TTF).